# Date generated from scriplet set as default value in textfield

Tags: jsp, date, struts2, textfield

I have this scriplet in my JSP and I want it to be somehow include as a default value in my `<s:textfield>`

```
<%java.text.DateFormat df = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd"); %>
```

How can I access variable `df`? I'm thinking like this:

```
<s:textfield name="mediaBean.acquireDate" style="width:150px;" 
        theme="simple" id="datepicker" type="text" 
        value="%{df.format(new java.util.Date())}" />
```

I tried to directly put it as `value="%{new java.util.Date()}` and it worked but without format. I want to have the `yyyy/MM/dd` format.

Help please. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use scriplets, use tag libs. What you want can be done with Struts2 tags `<s:date>` and `<s:param>`.

```
<s:textfield name="mediaBean.acquireDate" style="width:150px;" theme="simple" id="datepicker" type="text">
  <s:param name="value">
    <s:date name="new java.util.Date()" format="yyyy/MM/dd"/>
  </s:param>
</s:textfield>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the scripting variable like this

```
<s:set var="df" value="%{new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('yyyy/MM/dd')}"/>
```

then reference it

```
<s:textfield name="mediaBean.acquireDate" style="width:150px;" 
        theme="simple" id="datepicker" type="text" 
        value="%{#df.format(new java.util.Date())}" />
```

Comment: this also worked fine! i just edit  quotation of "yyyy/MM/dd" to single quote('yyyy/MM/dd'). thank you!

Comment: do you think that parametrize textfield is better solution to you?

Comment: ah yes, i think it's better but my basis is only because it's easy for me to read that code since its not a combination of scriplet and struts2 tag. i just came up only with this question about scriplet because i thought there is no way how to do it in struts2, but i learned both from your answers, i just can't upvote your solutions cause i dont have enough reputation

Comment: with s:param tag you can parametrize other tags, that's good but don't you think that parametrizing textfield looks ugly and placing such names in the tags has no meaning that leads to errors only.